# Failing to set a default value to the composite component

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I have a `List<String>` and I successfully represent it in a datatable; now I am trying to create a composite component out of it, but it seems I keep having trouble understanding how `StateHelper` does work.

What I want to do is, if the `value` attribute passed by xhtml evaluates to `null`, to create a new `List<String>` automatically. Right now, the only possible action is clicking a button that adds a new item to the list.

My component

```
<cc:interface componentType="testComponent">
  <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.util.List"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
  <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
  <p:dataTable id="data" value="#{cc.data}" var="_data">
    <p:column headerText="Nombre / Relación">
      <h:outputText value="#{_data}" />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

  <p:commandButton value="Añadir" process="@this" update="data"
    actionListener="#{cc.addData}" ajax="true"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

The component bean is

```
@FacesComponent("testComponent")
public class TestComponent extends UIOutput implements NamingContainer {
  private static final String LISTA_DATOS = "LST_DATOS";

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestComponent.class.getName());

@Override
public String getFamily() {
  return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
}

public List<String> getData() {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<String> data = (List<String>) this.getStateHelper().get(LISTA_DATOS);
  return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
  this.getStateHelper().put(LISTA_DATOS, data);
}

public void addData() {
  List<String> data = (List<String>)this.getData();
  data.add("HOLA");
  this.setData(data);
}

public void init() {
  log.info("En init()");
  if (this.getStateHelper().get(LISTA_DATOS) == null) {
    if (this.getValue() == null) {
      this.getStateHelper().put(LISTA_DATOS, new ArrayList<String>());
    } else {
      this.getStateHelper().put(LISTA_DATOS, this.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

The component is called like that

```
<h:form>
  <imas:editorTest value="#{testBean.data1}"/>
</h:form>
<h:form>
  <imas:editorTest value="#{testBean.data2}"/>
</h:form>
```

with `testBean` being:

```
private List<String> data1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ONE", "TWO", "SIXTYNINE"));
private List<String> data2 = null;

public List<String> getData1() {
  return this.data1;
}

public void setData1(List<String> data1) {
  this.data1 = data1;
}

public List<String> getData2() {
  return this.data2;
}

public void setData2(List<String> data2) {
  this.data2 = data2;
}
```

The issue I found is that, when passing `data2` (the `null` list), clicking the button adds a new item but only the first two times; after that, no matter how many times I click the button, no new items are added to the list (no exception shown in the log). On the opposite, there is no problem adding as many items as I wish to the component initialized with `data1`.

One thing that I have observed and that leads me to thinking that I am misusing `getStateHelper` is that, when I click the button, the `init()` method is executed twice and, at that time, `this.getStateHelper().get(LISTA_DATOS)` is `null`, while I expected it to be not null due to having initialized it when the component was first rendered. I expected `getStateHelper`  to carry such state between invocations, where am I wrong?.

Oh! I am using Wildfly 8.1 (no upgrades) with JDK 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper, I found some evidence of a bug, so [I reported it](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3786). I'll update the answer to see if it is really a bug or some big misconception from me.